# CoreUI React Nav Configuration

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, core-ui

I am using the CoreUI React Free Template to build out a React frontend project. The Sidebar component uses a navigation array of objects, which contains properties that are used to create CoreUI elements. Each object in the array has a "to" property, which provides the created nav item with a link, like so:

```
const nav = [
{
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Account',
    to: '/user/:id/profile',
    icon: 'cil-user',
  }
]
```

The nav array is imported into a component and passed as a render prop to a CCreateElement component that in turn creates CSidebarNavItems, which are glorified React Router Links.

**CCreateElement**

```
<CCreateElement
          items={navigation}
          {...props}
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />
```

I am trying to use dynamic urls in the "to" property, but my URLs return static strings `/users/:id/profile`. How I can get these rendered elements to generate these dynamic URLs?